# Folland Real Analysis 5.21

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, linear-transformations

The exercise reads as follows:

> If $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal Y$ are normed vector spaces, define
>   $\alpha:\mathcal X^*\times\mathcal Y^*\to(\mathcal X\times\mathcal Y)^*$ by
>
> $$\alpha(f,g)(x,y)=f(x)+g(y).$$
>
> Then $\alpha$ is an isomorphism which is isometric if we use the norm
>   $\|(x,y)\|=\max(\|x\|,\|y\|)$ on $\mathcal X\times\mathcal Y$, the
>   corresponding operator norm on $(\mathcal X\times\mathcal Y)^*$, and
>   the norm $\|(f,g)\|=\|f\|+\|g\|$ on $\mathcal X^*\times\mathcal Y^*$.

I have done everything but shown that $\alpha^{-1}$ is bounded and that $\alpha$ is an isometry.

For example, if $\alpha$ is an isometry, then

$$\|f+g\|_{(\mathcal X\times\mathcal Y)^*}=\|\alpha(f,g)\|_{(\mathcal X\times\mathcal Y)^*}=\|(f,g)\|_{\mathcal X^*\times\mathcal Y^*}=\|f\|_{\mathcal x^*}+\|g\|_{\mathcal Y^*},$$

which implies that $f$ and $g$ have the same sign everywhere, which makes no sense.

Comment: Not sure why you think that implies they have the same sign everywhere.  Be careful with your notation, which is potentially confusing.  Note that "$f+g$" has to be interpreted as the functional $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)+f(y)$ in order to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$\|\alpha(f,g)\|=\sup_{\|(x,y)\|=1}|f(x)+g(y)|=\sup_{\|x\|\vee\|y\|=1}|f(x)+g(y)|\approx\|f\|+\|g\|=\|(f,g)\|,$$
where the approximation follows by taking $x,y$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ and $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ arbitrarily close to $\|f\|$ and $\|g\|$.  It follows that $\alpha$ is an isometric isomorphism onto its image.  It remains only to show that it is surjective.  Indeed, if $h\in(X\times Y)^*$ then we can let $f(x)=h(x,0)$ and $g(y)=h(0,y)$ so that $f\in X^*$, $g\in Y^*$, and $h(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$.

Comment: Dear @Ben, could you develop a bit more on the approximation? I was able to show that $||\alpha(f, g)|| \leq ||f|| + ||g||$, but I don't know how to show the converse inequality.